# Copy ALL sites from remote server to local server Ubuntu & Filezilla

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, server, centos, filezilla

### Hey all,

I'm new to linux and still learning and I've searched and haven't been able to find the exact same issue anywhere......

I have a ***CentOS remote server*** hosting approximately 60 websites. Some just html, others custom scripts, and mostly wordpress.

I want to backup ALL the sites to my **local Ubuntu 16.04.1 lamp stack server**.

I am using Filezilla and I'm assuming it's not downloading the the /var/www folder because of permissions, but again, I'm new and don't know much.

## Questions:

***Do I need to change some settings in Filezilla?***

***Can I download them with terminal but in bulk?***

**I do understand I will have to grab all the databases and install them locally, separately, but are there any programs that could help automate this process, paid or free?**

Comment: Which account are you using to connect to the remote server? Please provide the output of running `ls -la /var/www` on the remote server to your question. Which operating system do you use on your local machine (relevant for software to automate this process)?

Comment: If you'll notice in the original post, I said that I am trying to transfer/copy websites from a REMOTE server, which is CentOS to a LOCAL server, which is Ubuntu 16.04.1.

Comment: Apologies I somehow misread that part. Could you please answer the other questions to determine issues regarding file permissions?